# Gazebo for testing offline with the new ABB Robot Driver

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the new [ABB robot driver](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver) requires the RWS/EGM connection to be up between the robot and the PC, I'm not sure how can I test some motion controllers offline.

Is there a "ready to use" implementation with the new driver?
Otherwise can you please tell me how can I test my motion controllers with Gazebo before testing them on the real robot? thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406385/gazebo-for-testing-offline-with-the-new-abb-robot-driver/) by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2022-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way to test -- ie: as close to the real robot + controller as possible -- would be to setup a cell in RobotStudio.

Note that Gazebo does not "use" nor is compatible with any real driver, as there is no real hardware for the driver to connect to or control.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1